# How to combine psd files as artboards in one psd file in Photoshop CC 2015?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, artboard

In new brand Photoshop CC 2015, adding artboards in one psd is now possible. Is there anyone who knows how to combine existing multiple psd files as artboards in one psd file in Photoshop CC 2015?

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately Adobe hasn't any tool for this.

You should do the same manually:

1. Open your PSD files
2. Select all of your layers
3. Make artboard from layers
4. Create a new file
5. Drag and drop your files' artboads to new file

Answer (score 2):

`File > New` and choose `Artboard` from the document type.

Load the images as layers.. then `Layer > New > Artboard from layers`

Or just choose `Layer > New > Artboard` then place your external files on the artboards.

You may want to check the new feature movies... https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/how-to/design-with-artboards.html

Comment: This how to do it manually. But actually I was looking for a feature to do it automatically. Adobe Acrobat has similar option, when you choose pdf files and right click and there is a option to combine all pdf files as one pdf. But I found out in the Adobe forums that there is no option to combine psd files in that way.